# Highcharts series not loading

Tags: highcharts

The highcharts chart is not showing.
`hc.xAxis[0].categories` are loaded ok, but `hc.series` are not

```
r.forEach(x => {
    var hc = Highcharts.chart('chart_div', {
        xAxis: { categories: x.categories },
        series: x.series,    
    });
    console.log(hc.series); // 1st
    console.log(x.series);  // 2nd
});
```

The 1st`console.log` shows no data and the 2nd one shows this:

> [{name: 'DE Shaw Comp (75;Q)', data: [100,100.5,101.91,103.03,104.37,103.85,103.22,104.77,105.71,105.5,107.08,107.51,106.33,107.18,107.18,108.68,109.44,110.87,110.53,111.75,115.21,116.83,117.41,116.82,116.24,118.21,119.99,121.79,121.54,122.88,122.27,123.86,124.6,126.22,128.36,124.77,129.14,], color: '#33a', label:{enabled:false}},{name: 'SPX', data: [100,94.93,94.53,100.77,101.05,102.59,102.69,106.34,106.21,106.08,104.02,107.58,109.54,111.49,115.64,115.6,116.65,118,118.57,120.86,120.93,123.26,125.99,129.53,130.81,138.16,132.77,129.2,129.56,132.36,133,137.79,141.96,142.57,132.67,135.04,122.65,119.76], color: '#a33', label:{enabled:false}},{name: 'HFRI RV: MULTI-STRATEGY', data: [100,98.37,97.83,99.53,101.19,102,102.66,103.99,104.87,105.72,106.02,106.54,107.66,109.08,109.73,110.07,110.37,110.38,110.58,111.34,111.51,111.95,112.37,112.46,113.29,114.53,114.13,113.48,114.48,115.17,114.97,116.2,116.26,116.68,115.32,114.95,,], color: '#aa3', label:{enabled:false}}]

which looks like a proper input.

Answer (score 0):

`series: eval(x.series)` is the solution
without eval x.series was interpreted as a string, not as an array of Object as I thought

Comment: Please explain why this is the solution so that when people read this answer in the future they can understand it better.